# PHP sequential foldernames from database id

Tags: php

I need to create unique foldernames for each database ID. 
Datasbe ID`s are unique and set to auto increment.
I need some nice function/class to convert id into a foldername which should be human unreadable but windows compatible.

Previously I was using [alphaID](http://kvz.io/blog/2009/06/10/create-short-ids-with-php-like-youtube-or-tinyurl/) but I ran into problems because it creates case sensitive names which becomes a problem for windows as it overwrites to same folder.
For example it would convert an Id 1 to Baaab and say 37 to baaaB.

Comment: Have you tried generating a hash of the Database ID (like `md5`)?

Comment: hashes are too long. and as u know if folder name is hash and u have file with bigger name inside it, windows gets in trouble again.

Comment: I could actually remove capital or small letters from main string from alphaID but i dont know mathematically how much it will reduce my limit ?

Comment: use a base26 number see answer below

Answer (score 0):

you can use a `base26` function, which will convert 1 to A and 27 to AA.

```
function num2alpha($n)
{
    for($r = ""; $n >= 0; $n = intval($n / 26) - 1)
        $r = chr($n%26 + 0x41) . $r;
    return $r;
}
```

Comment: This could be used but initial ofler names with A , B C are not nice.